# Does a system with translational symmetry implies that space is homogeneous?

Tags: classical-mechanics, spacetime, symmetry

In my classical mechanics course, we sometimes described a system to have translational symmetry, and other times we said that it is homogenous in space and isotropic. While I know they are different, I am not sure how, and what each word exactly means.

Comment: Did you ask your teacher?

Comment: He isn't really going to help, that's why I posted the question here. @BobD

Comment: Just curious, but why isn’t he really going to help?

Comment: due to language barriers :) @BobD